# How to draw a sickle using widget in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I usually used to export as an SVG file, but I want to know if it is possible to draw this shape using only widget

Like this
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZCJZa.png

Also how to make statistic usage as the above pic

Comment: try this https://shapemaker.web.app/#/

Comment: I prefer to code manually, don't like to use a generator tools

Answer (score 0):

You can use this tool https://www.flutterclutter.dev/tools/svg-to-flutter-path-converter

Which convert your SVG file into `CustomPainter` Class in flutter

**Edit**:
If you don't have SVG file. Simple draw to Circle intersected with each other then clip the drawing in `CustomPainter` class

```
class Sickle extends CustomPainter {
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    Paint outerPaint = Paint(); //Border Color
    Paint innerPaint = Paint(); //Blind it with backgroun Color

    outerPaint.color = Colors.lightBlue;
    innerPaint.color = Colors.white;

    // Clip the circle
    canvas.clipRect(Rect.fromLTWH(
        size.width / 2 - 20, size.height / 2 - 20, size.width, size.height));

    //Border Circle
    canvas.drawCircle(
        Offset(size.width / 2, size.height / 2), size.width / 2, outerPaint);
    // Inner Circle
    canvas.drawCircle(
        Offset(size.width / 2, size.height / 2), size.width / 3, innerPaint);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: I've tried, I found some issue that svg does not really work well, I successfully converted a bell svg file to CustomPainter, but with the shape of half circle / Sickle like the given screenshot above did not convert properly, it just like a circle of the full moon

Comment: @IvanJoeHann Did you tried the clipping method? It gave me your desired result. The code descried clipping method